# Store Data In a Generic List and use Linq

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-sql

Model.cs contains the Data of the User which is stored in a list type Now We have to fetch all those students whose `age` is more than `25`.

```
public class Model
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sports { get; set; }


        List<Model> objModels = new List<Model>() {
            new Model { Name = "Manish", Age = 27, Sports = "Cricket" },
            new Model { Name = "Rajan", Age = 25, Sports = "FootBall" },
            new Model { Name = "Prashant", Age = 25, Sports = "Kabaddi" },
            new Model { Name = "Garima", Age = 24, Sports = "Ludo" },
            new Model { Name = "Neha", Age = 25, Sports = "Carom" }
        };
    }
```

ModelController.cs

```
public class ModelController : Controller
    {

        // GET: Model
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Model> objModel = new List<Model>();
            var query = from models in objModel select models;
            foreach(var item in query.ToList())
            {
                objModel.Add(
                    new Model
                    {
                        Name = item.Name.ToString(),
                        Age = int.Parse(item.Age.ToString()),
                        Sports = item.Sports.ToString()
                    });

            }
            return View(objModel);
        }
    }
```

But The object is always `empty` because it is not fetching the data from the model class.

Comment: you're not using the list in the Model class ,objModel  is new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBCOntext.cs - a new class for Handeling The Data.

```
public class DBContext
{
    List<Model> objModel = new List<Model>();
   public List<Model> GetData()
    {
        objModel.Add(new Model
        {
            Name = "Manish",Age = 27,Sports = "Cricket"
        });
        objModel.Add(new Model
        {
            Name = "Rajan",Age = 25,Sports = "FootBall"
        });
        objModel.Add(new Model
        {
            Name = "Prashant", Age = 25,Sports = "Kabaddi"
        });
        objModel.Add(new Model
        {
            Name = "Garima", Age = 24,Sports = "Ludo"
        });
        objModel.Add(new Model
        {
            Name = "Neha",Age = 25,Sports = "Carom"
        });

        return objModel;
    }
}
```

And Controller class to access all the DBContext Data which can be used to send the data to the `View`

```
List<Model> objModel = new List<Model>();
    // GET: Model
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        DBContext db = new DBContext();

        var query = from models in db.GetData() where models.Age>25  orderby models.Age select models;
        foreach (var item in query.ToList())
        {
            objModel.Add(
                new Model
                {
                    Name = item.Name.ToString(),
                    Age = int.Parse(item.Age.ToString()),
                    Sports = item.Sports.ToString()
                });

        }
        return View(objModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you tried to do:

```
 public class Model
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Sports { get; set; }
        public List<Model> Models
        {
            get
            {
                return objModels;
            }

            set {
                Model = value;
            }

        }

        List<Model> objModels = new List<Model>() {
            new Model { Name = "Manish", Age = 27, Sports = "Cricket" },
            new Model { Name = "Rajan", Age = 25, Sports = "FootBall" },
            new Model { Name = "Prashant", Age = 25, Sports = "Kabaddi" },
            new Model { Name = "Garima", Age = 24, Sports = "Ludo" },
            new Model { Name = "Neha", Age = 25, Sports = "Carom" }
        };
    }
```

And then use it in your controller as :

```
 List<Model> newModelList=new List<Model>();
 Model objModel = Model;
            var query = from models in objModel.Models where models.age<25 select models;
            foreach (var item in query.ToList())
            {
                newModelList.Add(
                    new Model
                    {
                        Name = item.Name.ToString(),
                        Age = int.Parse(item.Age.ToString()),
                        Sports = item.Sports.ToString()
                    });

            }
            return View(newModelList);
```

Comment: yeah i figured it out .... but what about the data how to store it now and how to access.